# Typescript: Passing dynamic data to the extended class

Tags: typescript

I wonder if anyone can help ?

I have a class that I need to extend from a 3rdparty. When extending I need to pass in data dynamically - hence this is the class

```
class AuthGuardNew extends AuthGuard("Needs changing") {


}
```

So what I want to do is something like this

```
new AuthGuardNew("Something different")
```

which behind the scenes would pass "Something different" to the extended class, instead of "Needs Changing"

If I use a constructor like

```
constructor(type:string) {

}
```

But I how can I pass this into AuthGuard when its already been extended ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

If i try doing

```
export class AuthGuardNew extends AuthGuard {
  constructor(type?: string) {
    super(type)
  }
```

I get a typescript error stating that

> Type '(type?: string | undefined) => Type' is not a
>   constructor function type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long story short is that you can't. `AuthGuard` is a function that creates a class, not a class. There is no class to extend until you know the value of `type`.

Instead you can create a new function that constructs the class once you know the value of `type`.

```js
const AuthGuardNew = (type?: string) =>
    class extends AuthGuard(type || 'Needs changing') { 
        // You are free to override anything you need, you are defining a class
        myExtension(): number {
            return 10;
        }
    }
```

`AuthGuardNew` is again a function that creates a class, not a class.

```js
const SomethingDifferentAuthGuard = AuthGuardNew('Something different');

// SomethingDifferentAuthGuard is now a class that extends AuthGuard('Something different') 
// so we can instantiate and use it as such
console.log(new SomethingDifferentAuthGuard().myExtension())
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, Can't believe I missed that. Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You would simply call super in the constructor e.g.

```
class AuthGuardNew extends AuthGuard {
    constructor(type: string) {
        super(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is AuthGuard

export declare const AuthGuard: (type?: string) => Type<IAuthGuard>;